# Writing a generic trait implementation with IntoIterator trait, but only for immutable reference implementors

Tags: rust, traits

I am defining a trait that takes in a `i: &I` parameter. I would like to use this `i` value in a `for` loop.

For example:

```
struct Test;

trait Bar<I> {
    fn bar(&self, i: &I);
}

impl<T, I: IntoIterator<Item=T>> Bar<I> for Test {
    fn bar(&self, i: &I) {
        for x in i {
            println!("woo!");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    let test = Test;
    test.bar(&vec);
}
```

[Playground link](http://is.gd/OkuUHo)

This results in the error:

```
<anon>:10:9: 12:10 error: the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `&I` [E0277] <anon>:10         for x in i { <anon>:11             println!("woo!"); <anon>:12         } <anon>:10:9: 12:10 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277 <anon>:10:9: 12:10 note: `&I` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method <anon>:10:9: 12:10 note: required by `core::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter` error: aborting due to previous error playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

I was playing around with using the `Deref` trait to see if I could get something to work, but to no avail.

I would really like to keep the immutable reference in the function definition as this trait is attempting to be generic over many types, and defining the other implementations using `Bar<&'a I>` has lead to some other lifetime related issues that I have been having trouble with as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Saying that `I` is an `IntoIterator` doesn't say anything about `&I`, e.g. `x..y` is an `IntoIterator` (because it is an `Iterator` and all of them are), but `&(x..y)` is not.

You specifically want to bound `&I`, which fortunately can be done via a `where` clause, e.g.

```
impl<I, T> Bar<I> for Test 
    where for<'a> &'a I: IntoIterator<Item = T>
{
    fn bar(&self, i: &I) {
        for x in i {
            println!("woo!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `for<'a>` just means "for any lifetime `'a`", and so the `where` clause is saying that `&I` is always an `IntoIterator` (just writing `where &I: IntoIterator` isn't quite enough).

There's some choices to be made about the `T` parameter there, e.g.

1. `IntoIterator<Item = T>`
2. `IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>`
3. remove the parameter entirely and just write `IntoIterator`

The best choice will depend on exactly what you're doing with it. For the specific example in the question, I would go with 3, since the `Item` type doesn't matter at all. Number 2 makes sense because almost all types that have `&T` implement `IntoIterator` will yield references (it also seems to avoids most of the bugs/general difficulties the compiler currently has about reasoning about universal quantification over lifetimes, which hit 1 and 3).

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, [by convention](http://aturon.github.io/style/naming/conversions.html), methods whose name starts with `into` take their argument by value and transform it into another value, usually reusing some resources from the original value. The `IntoIterator` trait and its `into_iter` follow that convention.

Are you sure you need to use `&I` in your trait? Your codes works just fine with `I`. That's because there is an implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&Vec<T>`. That's why one can write `for x in &v` where `v` is a `Vec`.

```
struct Test;

trait Bar<I> {
    fn bar(&self, i: I);
}

impl<T, I: IntoIterator<Item=T>> Bar<I> for Test {
    fn bar(&self, i: I) {
        for x in i {
            println!("woo!");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec!(1, 2, 3);
    let test = Test;
    test.bar(&vec);
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/fEFyw9)